# Is there a way to map the regions of a laptop's touchpad so that they function like the keys of a number pad?

Tags: touchpad, keyboard-layout, synaptics

I'm wondering if anyone has already tried something like this, or if there's a feasible way of configuring Synaptics to do it. Or anything else that might work.

I'm thinking of the traditional keyboard layout, with the 3x3 grid of number keys on the righthand side:

```
-------------
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
```

Of course, that doesn't leave space for "0" or any operators (+, -, /, *, etc), but with a little creativity I think it could be worked out. And it would be nice to have a quick way to activate it too, perhaps by reassigning a lesser-used Fn key, so you could switch between that and normal touchpad gestures.

Does this idea appeal to anyone else? Or just me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Good one! I think you have an original idea!  And if you're a programmer: get to it!  Nice to have lying around for laptops that don't have a numeric keypad!

Comment: Only upvoted now as I ran out of votes yesterday...  **;-)**